# accessing dynamically created form elements from a thread in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, dynamically-generated

I am new to VB and .Net and I have a task that I am unable to proceed.

1. I start a thread when screen1 Loads. User then goes to screen2.
2. On screen2 the thread is still running behind. when the user performs an action(say click) on screen2, it will trigger the thread to access elements on screen2
3. The elements in screen 2 are dynamically created and not designed in IDE.

So in essence a thread that is created on one form needs to access dynamically created form elements on another form.

If my question is too simple, please forgive me. If it is not clear please let me know and I will rephrase it.

Note: The element that I am talking about is basically a picture box inside a flow layout panel.

Thanks in advance
All help is eagerly(biting nails now) awaited and greatly appreciated.

EDIT

1. Lets say a thread called ctThread was started in dashboard screen

   ctThread.start()
2. This thread is running endlessly, waiting for a trigger event.
3. Meanwhile User has gone to a screen called QuizScreen and on this screen(form) I have to update some dynamically created elements whose names I know.
4. So when the time is right for ctThread which is waiting (Listener Thread) it will call the sub below.

Sub

```
public sub changeComputerStatus(ByVal node)
    Dim flowpanel As FlowLayoutPanel = CType(QuizScreen.FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls("flow_" + node), FlowLayoutPanel)
    Dim pictControl As PictureBox = CType(flowpanel.Controls("pict_" + node), PictureBox)
    pictControl.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(Application.StartupPath & "\images\application-on.png")
end sub
```

here node keeps changing. This is how I differentiate each control I create.

Note : This thread was started in a screen called dashboardscreen and the user is now on a different screen QuizScreen.

The first line of the sub I gave above runs and returns nothing to the flowpanel. Hence when It goes to the next line, it is not able to use the nothing as reference. And hence the above mentioned error.

Comment: Which part of this task are you having trouble with?  Have you tried it and it's not working properly?  Or are you getting an error?  Or are you just asking for general advice on how to even go about doing something like that?

Comment: Hi steven thanks for replying. I get an error while trying to access the dynamically created element. The error is "Object reference not set to an instance of an object". If I try to access the same element(dynamic element) using an event on the form, I am able to do that. But while trying the same code inside a thread. it doesnt find  the element for some reason.

Comment: I am a web developer(php/python) basically caught in a vb.net project. Application development is quite new to me.

Comment: It probably has little to do with the threading, but it's impossible to say with so few details.  It would be immensely helpful if you could post a simplified example of code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Dear Steven I just updated with some sample and more explanation. Could you please help me sort it out. Thanks again.

Comment: When you call that `changeComputerStatus` method from the other thread, are you doing so by invoking it on the UI thread, or are you just calling it directly from the background thread?  (FYI, when responding to someone in particular in the comments, instead of saying "Dear so-and-so", say "@so-and-so".  That way they will get a notification that you said something to them.  If you don't do that, the other person won't be notified.)

Answer (score 1):

Two things.

1. The most important thing you must know is that you cannot directly access a control's properties from a background thread. Controls may only be manipulated from the foreground UI thread. In order to access controls from a background thread, you need to use some form of asynchronous programming, e.g. creating delegates a la .NET 1.x - 3.5 or using the new `Task<T>` and `async` and `await` keywords.
2. Did you actually add the dynamically created controls to the form's control collection? Mind you, you'll still need to access the controls via delegates or some other asynchronous method as explained in 1 above.

**UPDATE:**

To answer the question in the OP's comment below: you can also `Invoke` a method on a UI object. Basically, you're telling .NET to run the invoked method and it runs on the UI object's creating thread (in this case, the UI thread), which is what you want. This will allow you (depending on the method or property invoked) to "update" the control "from the background"—again, this is all sleight of hand; when invoking a method on a UI object, the invkoked method runs on the UI thread possibly using data passed into said method from the background task.

Also, check out the MSDN documentation on the `BacgkroundWorker` (this was introduced in .NET 2.0 and is superseded by the `async` and `await` keywords along with `Task<T>` in .NET 4.5). There is lots of documentation available that explains exactly how to do what you're asking. It's not hard to find by performing a quick search on MSDN or Bing (or your preferred search engine).

Comment: Dear @fourpastmidnight                                                       Its a long time since I saw this. Since I was shifted to a different task, I left this. Now I am back to the original task. So thanks for replying first of all. But fourpastmidnight I used delegates and it still doesnt work.